# How to remove whitespace that occurs after a comma

Tags: regex, r, string, trim

I have a vector that looks like this

```
vector = c('hello, how are you, I am good', 
           'the sky is blue, isnt that nice')
```

I want to remove the spaces within each ' ' that come after a comma

i.e. the output should look like:

```
'hello,how are you,I am good','the sky is blue,isnt that nice'
```

Comment: `gsub(",\\s", ",", vector)`

Comment: Or just for fun `gsub("(?<=,)\\s", "", vector, perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 3):

To close this question:

```
gsub(", +", ",", vector)
```